# How to send email using cakephp framework?

Tags: email, cakephp, confirmation

No clue how to send an email as soon as an order has been saved.  The purchaser will enter in an email in the order form and a confirmation email is sent using CakePHP 2.0.  I've tried so many different ways but I'm a noob and need direction.  Please direct me!

```
  <?
    class OrdersController extends AppController
    {
       var $name = 'Orders';
       var $scaffold;
       function add()
       {            
          if ($this->request->is('post'))
          {
               if ($this->Order->save($this->request->data)) 
               {
                   $this->Session->setFlash('Order has been saved');
                   $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
               }
               else 
               {
                   $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add order');
               }
          }
       }
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: I was having a lot of problems with this when I was testing it locally, but it worked fine when it was set up on an actual web server with a domain and email addresses. Maybe that could help, but I still don't understand what the problem was.

Comment: set up mail server for you in localhost.And then use swiftmailer component.Include swift mailer in you component array in controller.Its works well.I had used it in my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CakePHP provides a CakeEmail class for this purpose: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html